# Get unique value count from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting

I have `javascript` `array` and I want to get `count` key in this response.

Here is the response:

```
var events = [
  {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
      "events": [
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 675,
          "isSelected": false
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 690,
          "isSelected": false
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 690,
          "isSelected": true
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 705,
          "isSelected": false
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 705,
          "isSelected": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "message": "Data found"
  }
]
```

And I want this array response like that:

```
var events = [
  {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
      "events": [
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 675,
          "isSelected": false,
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 690,
          "isSelected": true,
          "count": 2
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 705,
          "isSelected": true,
          "count": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    "message": "Data found"
  }
]
```

I need to add `count` key and count how many times same `startTime` value occurred and remove duplicate `object` based on `startTime`. Please help me.

Comment: Is it necessary that all other fields will be same if `startTime` is same? I mean if there any case when `startTime` is same but `dayOfWeek` is different, then that will also get removed

Comment: @AbhishekKumarTiwari yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reduce the sub array and count the occurrences like so:

```js
var events = [
  {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
      "events": [
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 675,
          "isSelected": false
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 690,
          "isSelected": false
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 690,
          "isSelected": true
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 705,
          "isSelected": false
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "dayOfWeek": 1,
          "startTime": 705,
          "isSelected": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "message": "Data found"
  }
];

events = events.map(e => {
  e['data']['events'] = e['data']['events'].reduce((acc, ev) => {
    const index = acc.findIndex(existingEv => existingEv['startTime'] == ev['startTime']);
    
    if(index != -1) {
      acc[index]['count'] = acc[index]['count'] + 1;
      acc[index]['isSelected'] = acc[index]['isSelected'] || ev['isSelected'];
    } else {
      acc.push({
        ...ev,
        count: 1
      });
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return e;
});

console.log(events);
```

Comment: I have checked your answer but I need `isSelected` key `true`. Check my question with response.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.filter():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
const _events_ = [];
const eventsNonDuplicated = events[0].data.events.filter((ev) => {
   if (!_events_.some((v) => v == ev.startTime) ) {
     _events_.push(ev.startTime);
      return ev;
   }
});
console.log(eventsNonDuplicated);
```